# How to create color scheme from two colors?

Tags: color, color-theory

Are there any tools for creating a color scheme based on two specific colors (or resources that explain the technique/intuition behind it), since the only ones I have found are based around creating a color scheme from one base color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/) which is an awesome site, where you can generate awesome color palettes.

there is this cool feature where in you can start with two colors then lock both of them and generate color scheme until you feel that color scheme works for you.

[image]

and there are many other sites but this one just works for me. hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your input! 
Do you know what's the idea behind the selection of other colors? Does it adjust those colors to fit certain schemes e.g. complementary?

Comment: Not only complementary, hue, brightness, saturation also does come into the picture. if you want to know more in detail, [Fabrizio Bianchi](https://twitter.com/_fbrz) creator of coolors himself is the man. :)

Comment: No worries eventually you will have :). glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with it by using **gradients** and pick any color in the middle of it.

**Example Here**

[image]

**NOTE: This only works for colors close to each other in the color specturm or it will look weird (mileage may vary)**